# maven copy subfolder from target to an external directory

Tags: java, maven, build, copy, war

I have a maven Java web application which generates a WAR file, I want to be able to copy a specific folder inside target to an external directory on my filesystem:

app folder structure:

```
├───app
│   ├───css
│   ├───img
│   ├───js
│   ├───lib
│   
├───META-INF
└───WEB-INF
    └───lib
```

I want to be able to copy only the "app" folder from target to a specific external directory after the build is completed successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Maven resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html) can help you to do that.
Other possible choices are [Maven antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/run-mojo.html) or [copy Maven plugin](https://github.com/evgeny-goldin/maven-plugins/tree/master/copy-maven-plugin).

Technically, a plugin cannot be executed after the end of the build, but you can choose an appropriate phase to link your plugin execution to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could make it work using copy-resources from maven-resources-plugin